# Вопрос о распределении памяти

Tags: c++

Допустим есть такой кусок кода (набросал на коленке ради примера).

```
int size = 10 // глобальная переменная
int* something(int *array){
     int *newarray = new int [size*2];
     for(int i = 0;i < size; ++i)
         newarray[i] = array[i];
     size *= 2;
     return newarray;
}
```

Пример не несет никакой смысловой нагрузки. Есть массив размером n (размер глобальная переменная), передаем его в функцию, там массив расширяем и передаем его обратно.

Вопрос: В теле программы мы выделяем и удаляем динамический массив, окей. Но в функции же происходит так же выделение памяти под другой динамический массив который заменит собой старый. Что при этом происходит? Память так и остается за старым/новым или трется? Вопрос пришел в голову совершенно случайно.

Comment: у этого кода есть одна существенная проблема. Его можно вызвать как `arr = something(arr);` так и `arr1 = something(arr2);`. И эти два варианта требуют разного подхода к освобождению памяти.

Comment: @KoVadim если эта функция есть метод класса, а array ничто иное как поле класса, то подход будет один. Вы правы, просто пример написанный для демонстрации.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Память, которая была выделена динамически (ну вы ведь по-любому создали массив `array` посредством `new[]`, а не адрес массива, созданного на стеке, передали), под старый массив (`int* array`) останется висеть в куче (т.к. все, что создается динамически остается висеть в куче), пока вы сами её не очистите (`delete[] array`).

Т.е. по факту вы лишь создали вдвое больший массив, который никак не связан со старым: вы просто скопировали значения элементов старого массива в элементы нового, а старый так и останется висеть в памяти, пока вы сами же его не удалите.

Comment: И как тогда производить замену одного массива на другой если например старый массив по сути это поле класса.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda а вам принципиальна работа с динамическим массивом вот так напрямую? Просто выйдет куда удобнее и правильнее использовать готовые _stl-ные_ контейнеры, которые за нас воротят динамической памятью (если удобнее, то могу привести пример с использованием таковых).

Comment: в данный момент принципиальна, потому что захотелось сделать, ради практики конечно, свою обертку под обычный массив. наверное Вам знакомо чувство строительство велосипеда только ради интереса.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Так прямо расширить не получится, т.к. выделится новая память в другом месте, а такой массив предполагает создание памяти одним куском (чтобы можно было перемещаться по ней посредством `array++`, например). Вообще "дополняемый массив" такой лучше бы делать как очередь (`Queue`) и для каждого её элемента отдельно выделять память, причем каждый элемент хранит ссылку на последующий, но если принципиально именно так, то сейчас могу привести пример как это сделать (выйдет не очень красиво, но работоспособно :D)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda На счет очереди там каждый элемент должен хранить указатель на следующий, а не ссылку (описался). Вам, все-таки, привести пример реализации той очень странной штуки, что вам нужна или вы через очередь (Queue) попробуете лучше организовать все?

Answer (score 5):

Любое выделение памяти в куче (`new`, `malloc()`) должно всегда сопровождаться соответствующим её освобождением (`delete`, `free()`), иначе произойдёт утечка памяти.

Если сделать дважды выделение памяти под массив, и только один раз освободить, то будет утечка памяти.

```
int *x = new int[10];
x = new int[20]; // утечка - мы теряем указатель на область памяти, выделенную ранее
delete []x; //освобождаем память, выделенную во второй раз. Память, выделенная изначально недоступна, но так же не освобождена.
```

В `delete` и `free()` должен передаваться тот же указатель, который был получен при `new` или `malloc()`.

Память, выделенная через `new` или `malloc()` если не освобождать вручную считается используемой процессом пока тот не завершит свою работу.

Comment: тогда получается, по хорошему необходимо перед 'return' производить удаление старого массива ('array')

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, да, это так. Для того, чтобы максимально избегать утечек  я лично взял для себя правило выделять и освобождать память в одном и том же блоке кода. Либо как страховку можно (и нужно) использовать `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Хорошая практика. Ещё есть RAII.

Comment: @ArmanHayots можно подробней ?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda, `RAII` это идиома программирования, которая является чуть ли не основной для С++ - создание и разрущение объекта должно происходить в одном блоке кода. Это выполняется автоматически через конструкторы-деструкторы классов, и так же для "умных указателей", отпадает необходимость следить за освобождением памяти.